# mtpro2: PARENS environment error

Tags: macros, errors, mtpro

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\begin{document}
    \[\begin{PARENS}    
    \frac{x}{y} 
    \end{PARENS} \]
\end{document}
```

The code above gives the error

`Argument of \frac has an extra }. \frac`.

But if i write the `\frac{x}{y}` command in `{}` then there is no error.

I just want to learn how  i can fix it?

Comment: According to http://www.pctex.com/files/managed/1/1b/mtpro2Abbrev.pdf, `\PARENS` is a command expecting an argument, so `\PARENS{\frac{x}{y}}` should be correct. Can you test? (I don't have `mtpro2` installed.)

Comment: @JosephWright Tested it; is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation for `mtpro2`](http://pctex.com/files/managed/1/1b/mtpro2Abbrev.pdf) makes it clear that `\PARENS` is a command taking one argument

```
\PARENS{\frac{x}{y}}
```

It's unsurprising that if you use it as an environment odd things happen (here, it grabs `\frac` but not the arguments to `\frac`, then problems arise as `\frac` looks for two arguments and fails to find them).

Comment: i wonder if there is a way to use \PARENS as environment without using {}. Can we add {} automatically, for example, using a command.

Comment: @mert You could define a command which uses the `environ` package to collect up the content of the environment then use it as the argument to `\PAREN`. I think that would be a separate question :-)